# Shutting Down NFS services: FAILED

Tags: linux, service, nfs, rhel

I am using RHEL5.5. I wanted to shutdown nfs services in order to install and run a package. The installation itself tried shutting down the service and it failed.

It keeps saying "**Shutting down nfs services [Failed]**".

What is the problem here and how to shut it down?

Comment: `/usr/sbin/exportfs -v` will show what's exported. `/usr/sbin/exportfs -au` will stop sharing whatever is exported. Good luck. Just try this command first before stopping the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said it is failing because of the nfs init script checking the number of lines in the exportfs and your /etc/export file empty, do the following

1. navigate to /etc/rc.d/init.d/
2. back up the nfs script (you can copy it to a different dir and rename it to nfs.bk)
3. find the following section in the script:

   Do it the last so that clients can still access the server
   when the server is running.

   cnt=`/usr/sbin/exportfs -v | /usr/bin/wc -l`

   if **[ $cnt = 0 ]**; then

   action $"Shutting down NFS services: " /usr/sbin/exportfs -au

   else

   action $"Shutting down NFS services: " /bin/false

   fi

The bold section indicate that the if statement check whether exportfs -v has more than 0 lines. If you run this yourself you will find out that it actually has 0 lines which cause the script to fail. So change [ $cnt -gt 0 ] to [ $cnt = 0 ] and everything will work.

Take extra precautions when changing system scripts. Make sure you back the nfs script first and test it by running the following:

```
service nfs stop
```

DO NOT REBOOT so it case something doesn't work you can always restore the original nfs scritp.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually shutting down the service using the command

```
service nfs stop
```

and then try installing the package again.

Comment: I tried this also. But the service is still not getting shut down.

Comment: @user3401287 : "shutting down NFS services : FAILED" may also be because of the nfs init script checking the number of lines in the exportfs. Is your /etc/export file empty?

Comment: yes it is empty! So what is the solution now?